# aws elasticbeanstalk configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I recently discovered the ability for functions in ebextensions configs, but can't seem to figure out the syntax. Maybe what I'm trying to do is just not possible?

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    SERVER_URL: { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBEnvironmentName", "EndpointURL"] }
```

My objective here is to pass in the current endpointURL to the application. I have also tried getting just the CNAME and doing a FN::Join